TO_CHAR to format decimal places not working for whole numbers
I have the below TO_CHAR SQL function in Oracle DB where I simply want to format the number to show as a decimal to 2 decimal places. The below function is what I thought would accomplish that, however as you can see the data being returned back is only displaying the decimal point and not the zeros (since this is a whole number).
Do I need this wrapped in some conditional function to add the 2 zeros after the decimal place? I only want to do that if it's a whole number, as some values in this column are already are in decimal format. Also the number will be a varying size so I hope the above function accomplishes the varying length the number could be.
SELECT   to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.99') TRANSACTION_COST
        ,B.TRANSACTION_COST TRANS_COST_ORIGINAL
  FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
       CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B

Results:
TRANSACTION_COST    TRANS_COST_ORIGINAL
1800.               1800

Expected Results:
1800.00

.00 instead of .99 ?

What to do with numbers having more than two decimal places? Should 123.456 be formatted as 123.45 or 123.46? Or should they stay as they are? Would be useful to show more sample data and the expected result.

And what are you going to do with the results? Do you really want to change the data type from numeric to varchar? Note formatting is often better be done in the application rather than in SQL.

@JonasMetzler In the case with numbers that already have more than 2 decimal places I just want it rounded to 2 decimal places, which I assume I can wrap the ROUND function into this to do that, or will 'FM99990.90' already accomplish that too?

@Nick It seems that simply using FM99990.90 without further function "rounds up" the numbers like also ROUND does. If you want to cut off trailing digits rather than rounding, use TRUNC. See some tests here: sample fiddle

Change the last 9 to a 0:  to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90'). 9 drops leading 0s before the decimal or trailing ones after the decimal. 0 preserves them.

That is exactly what I needed! Will this still work ok for another value with decimals already i.e. 128.457 ? It will just remove the last digit and become 128.45?

if you have any question about what something will do, try it out. use the dual table: select to_char(128.457,'FM99990.90') from dual and adjust the format model as needed until you get what you want. you can easily google up docs on the format model and the characters you can use.

Thanks to both of you for your feedback!
